# What's process constitutionalism?

Tags: european-union, terminology

Can someone pls explain like I'm 5 what process constitutionalism is? The author failed to define it, and I see no simple answers after [Googling "process constitutionalism"](https://www.google.com/search?q="process+constitutionalism").

Robert Schütze. [*European Union Law* 2 ed. 2018](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/eu-law-9780198714927?cc=ca&lang=en&). p. 264. All emboldenings are mine.

> Which mechanism works best? States can be partly protected by a procedural
>   duty on the Union legislator to ‘think hard’ about subsidiarity. However, procedural
>   obligations only provide *some* protection of State autonomy. The Court of
>   Justice should thus be involved in setting a substantive subsidiarity standard. But
>   would the setting of hard limits for the Union legislator not be inherently anti-democratic?
>   This view is mistaken. For the democracy-centred
>   rationale behind
>   **process constitutionalism** is hard to apply to a federal context. Here the question
>   is *not* whether a non-democratic
>   court or a democratic parliament should
>   decide, but whether the democratic majority of the *Union* or the democratic
>   majority of a *State* should decide on the matter.

I transcribed just the tag line that appears along the red arrow below.

> [image]

Comment: It looks like the hard to parse sentence is incomplete and/or missing a comma or more.